# TSQL error: Operand data type bit is invalid for add operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am in the process of converting some Access queries into tsql and this error pops up when I try to execute the query.
I am guessing that SQL Server does not allow adding of 'bit' types, so I found the cultprit lines where that occurs and they are:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   [modules].[b]+[modules].[w]+[modules].[e]+[modules].[j]+
   [modules].[p]+[modules].[s] AS approvalRating, -- other columns here --
```

And:

```
ORDER BY [modules].[b]+[modules].[w]+[modules].[e]+[modules].[j]+
   [modules].[p]+[modules].[s],
   modulePriority.configPriority, 
   [modulePositionalData].[highPos]-[modulePositionalData].[lowPos]+1, 
   modulePositionalData.iMax;
```

Now I did not create the original Access queries and I have no idea what was the intention of adding that Boolean fields which makes it a bit problematic, but is there a way to allow the operations to be performed and result to be the same as performed by Access?

Comment: Unless `b`, `e`, `w`, etc, are extremely well established terms in your industry, you might also want to consider some renaming to make your system more readable in general.

Comment: Are the columns defined in Access as Yes/No columns? Because if so, Access does something truly horrible when you add such columns together/

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes they are. Could you explain what happens there and add an answer?

Comment: I have unaccepted the answer for now, until @Damien_The_Unbeliever or someone else could explain what Access does in this situation as I think it could be very relevant to this question.

Comment: In Access, if you add several Yes/No columns together, the resulting number is `-1 * number of yeses`. So 4 yeses and 2 noes, added together produces the result `-4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't add bit fields in sql server

But you can cast them to int

so

```
CAST(yourBitField as int) + CAST (yourSecondBitField as int)
```

By the way (would say it's due to [type preference order](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258264%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)), it will be ok if you cast only one of them

```
CAST(yourBitField as int) + yourSecondBitField
```

But casting all is probably "easier to read and understand".

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if Access does the same?

Comment: No... By the way, you can cast only one of them, it will be ok for the others.

Comment: Thanks again, worked. And the second hint also saved me some lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add bits in SQL Server, as they can only be 0 or 1. You can however convert them to integer values first and then add them. To convert a bit to an int, use the CAST function:

```
CAST([modules].[b] AS INT) + CAST([modules].[w] AS INT) + CAST([modules].[e] AS INT) ... etc
```

See more on SQL Server type conversion here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 0):

if the fields are fromt typ char it works. 
    SELECT [field1]+ [field2] as test  , [field3] 
    FROM [table]
    order by test

if the fiels are from an other type you must cast them

This works in my database

Answer (score 0):

As they are bits you can 'OR' them together with | :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx
This will give you the same result.